# Maximum size of UART receive buffer for ESP8266

Tags: uart, esp8266, sming

I am using SMING framework. What is the maximum size that the ESP8266 UART can receive at any one time? If I were to transmit a string of X bytes to ESP UART, what is the maximum size of X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware TX & RX FIFOs are 128 bytes long - However, this isn't really the "maximum" length it can receive or transmit, just the amount it can buffer at one time. Using the overrun interrupts, you can theoretically receive or send any arbitrary length.

Comment: Where can one modify the code to increase the FIFO size?

Comment: You can't increase the FIFO size, as it's an actual piece of hardware on the chip. What you can do, however, is create a _virtual_ buffer which copies the extra data out of the hardware FIFO when it's full. SMING has an example on how to call a function when data arrives here: https://github.com/SmingHub/Sming/blob/master/samples/Basic_Serial/include/SerialReadingDelegateDemo.h - You'd simply need to put the data from onData into, say, a large character array, and read it when you need it